# Contact Framework equivalent to ABAddressBook.ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook, cncontact, cncontactstore

I am migrating an application from the deprecated Address Book Framework to the new Contacts Framework. The application utilizes [`ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback) to be notified when another application changes a contact.

I am unable to find equivalent functionality in the Contacts Framework. Apple documentation says to use the default notification center with [the `CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification` notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification):

> The notification posted when changes occur in another `CNContactStore`.

Taking Apple's advice, my code looks like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "contactsChanged:",
    name: CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification,
    object: nil)
```

However, I have found two problems with this approach:

1. I am notified for *all* changes, including those made by my own application.
2. Notifications are spurious - I receive many notifications for a single change.

If I log the debug description of the notification when the change was made within my app, I get something like this:

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x7d3370e0 {name = CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification; userInfo = {
    CNNotificationOriginationExternally = 1;
    CNNotificationSourcesKey =     (
    );
}}
```

And if the changes are made externally:

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x7bf7a690 {name = CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification; userInfo = {
    CNNotificationOriginationExternally = 1;
    CNNotificationSourcesKey =     (
    );
}}
```

As you can see, nothing obvious with which to distinguish them.

Can anyone tell me how to get the same behavior from the Contacts Framework as one can get from `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback`?

Comment: self is referring to the class instance, where you are calling this method from.

Comment: @ogres sure, poor wording on my part. Basically, does passing in `self` achieve what I'm after (receiving only those changes from external apps)? For that to work, what _type_ would `self` be?

Comment: self could by any type, as long as it has addressBookDidChange: method declared.

Comment: OK, but what about my question regarding only external changes?

Comment: yes, you will receive notifications when it changes.

Comment: Yes, I do. But I receive them _even when it's my application making the change_. This is the point of my question: how do I receive them only for changes made by _other_ applications.

Comment: log notification and check if there is a difference between external and internal changes notification.

Comment: If documentation is right you should use only one CNContactStore in your application - then you should get only changes made by other apps.

Comment: @DanielS that's what I'm doing.

Comment: Given that this is a new framework, it's entirely possible that this is a bug/oversight. Maybe file a Radar about it?

Comment: What does your app's `NotificationCenter.default.post` code look like? Or, if this is fixed, can you post an answer (or select one) to explain?

Comment: I agree that this is a bug. I've worked around this issue by listening for `kABDatabaseChangedExternallyNotification` instead of `CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification`.

If you look at `.userInfo` from the `kABDatabaseChangedExternallyNotification`, you'll see that one of the notification's `ABSenderProcessName`s is `AddressBookSourceSync`. If you update a contact from your phone, you'll only get the `AddressBookSourceSync` notification.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd recommend [filing a bug with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) about the lack of a way to identify internal vs external changes in the API.

As a possible workaround, you could see if unregistering your observer before making a change and re-registering immediately afterward ensures that you miss all of your change notifications and still get all the external ones:

```
class ContactsThingy {

    var observer: NSObjectProtocol?
    let contacts = CNContactStore()

    func contactStoreDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        NSLog("%@", notification)
    }

    func registerObserver() {
        let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        observer = center.addObserverForName(CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), usingBlock: contactStoreDidChange)
    }

    func unregisterObserver() {
        guard let myObserver = observer else { return }
        let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        center.removeObserver(myObserver)
    }

    func changeContacts(request: CNSaveRequest) {
        unregisterObserver() // stop watching for changes
        defer { registerObserver() } // start watching again after this change even if error
        try! contacts.executeSaveRequest(request)
    }
}
```